# I can't seem to find android.R.id.radio0?(among others)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm dooing  [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#first) tutorial and at one point he uses the R.id.xxxx where x is the name/id of a control I'm using, if I understood it correctly.

Now I have two of those R thing's -.-' and one is android.R and the other is dk.ilizane.android.temperatur.R which doesn't contain any id at all so I kinda figured I will be using android.R.id but i'm looking for editText1, radio0, radio1 and it doesn't contain any of those.

Is there anyone kind enough to try explain this to me? I'm trying to learn this so I would appreciate if the answer wasn't just the correct code but an answer which I can

My code:

```
package dk.ilizane.android.temperatur;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Omregn extends Activity 
{
    private EditText text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.editText1);
    }

    public void myClickHandler(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) 
    {
    case android.R.id.button1:
        RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(dk.ilizane.android.temperatur.R);
        RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(android.R.id.radio1);
        if (text.getText().length() == 0) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
        if(celsiusButton.isChecked()){
            text.setText(String.valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));

        }else {
            text.setText(String.valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
        }
        if(fahrenheitButton.isChecked()){
            fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
            celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
            celsiusButton.setChecked(false);

        }
        break;
    }

    }
    private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit){
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
    }
    private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius){
        return ((celsius *9) / 5) + 32;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in dk.ilizane.android.temperatur.R.id.radio1. If you look at the tutorial in the main.xml file the ids of the RadioButtons are radio0 and radio1. Your projects custom resources will be compiled into a class named R in your package. In Eclipse there should be a gen src directory that contains the java file.

Comment: thanks a lot - I wrote much of the code in hand, instead of copy&paste so I would get a better feeling of how this work. This left more room for errors :/ now my question is answered, though another error is bordering me..  some resources.ap_ does not exist :S

Comment: Hey @Robby Pond Thanks, but how? the "play" button or the debug button both says its running and i tried to shut it down and open it up again without result. is there any button or hot-key to a "rebuild" feature? 
UPDATE: i have it compiling now, took some tweeks but apparently there is a different on just running it and debug it when you first open it op, would have thought it would rebuild before running it - wiping all earlier data. ^^ much to learn..! thanks alot for the help

Comment: @Hans-Henrik Choose project from the menu and choose clean.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `main.xml` under `/res/layout/`?  The `R` file you mentioned is generated as a way to reference your project resources.  Check that you have the same resources defined as the ones in the tutorial.  The `R` file will then exist as `dk.ilizane.android.temperatur.R` in the `/gen` directory.

Comment: Thanks to you both :P see my above comment on my new fancy error :P

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before, for some reason I had an `import android.R;` which causes conflict between `import android.R;` & `com.packagename.R`. If you delete the `import android.R;`, there will be no conflict & your code will compile.

But, if you really need the `import android.R;` then you have to specify which `R` you want.

For example, if you want to reference a `View` in you project you have to refer to the full path of the View like this `com.packagename.R.id.viewName`.